# Understanding payments w/Stripe on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand how to build stripe in Rails, but can't find any help on this:

I have a `user` model who has_many `campaigns`.

Each `campaign` has an amount that has to be charged.

My question is, should I make an Orders / Charges table with relations with Users and Campaigns, or can I just make a `payed` boolean column on `campaign` and use the success callback in Stripe to make it true?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fully understood your business logic. And since the question is regarding the database design and handling, all I can give are some general guidelines:

- Orders and Charges are [deprecated Stripe API's](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/older-apis). Please don't use them unless you are dealing with legacy codebase.
- What is your payment collection mode? Is it through a subscription or is it a one time thing? If it was a subscription, then I'd create the logic like this:

```markdown
- Each user will have a `has_one` association with a subscription table
- In subscription table have one field called status, which refers to the Stripe subscription status
- If the status is active, then it means that you have an active campaign which is paid for
```

Now to store your product info:

```markdown
- The subscription table can have a `has_one` association with a Product table
- The product table can have either `has_one` or `has_many` association with a Price table
```

And yes. You should always make use of Stripe webhooks to verify payment information due to the asynchronous nature of payments. In order to start/run the campaign for the user, all you have to do is check whether the subscription is active and any other business logic you have in place.